# pig script find rows differ just by one column

Tags: apache-pig

I need to take the average of third column , whenever first and second columns are same.
 Example input : `{1, 10, 11}, {1,10, 12} , {2, 5, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {2, 5, 12} {3, 6, 10}`

I understand `GROUP By` and  `AVG` function. can be used, But not sure how to use it in above context.

````
B = GROUP A BY name;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE A.name, AVG(A.gpa); ```

Expected : {1,10, 11.5}, {2, 5, 9}, {3, 6, 10}
````

Answer (score 0):

group by the first two columns and then use avg.

```
B = GROUP A BY (a1,a2);-- Note: use whatever is the column name instead of a1,a2
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (a1,a2),AVG(A.gpa);
```